# dynamic soql binding malformed query

Tags: apex

Is there anything wrong in this dynamic query.

I am trying to fetch child records(contacts) for all those accounts whose recordtype is 'Recordtype1'

```
string sobjectParent, 
relationName, 
fieldChild,
contactRT;
sobjectparent = 'Account';
relationName = 'Contacts';
fieldchild = 'LastName';
contactRT = 'Recordtype1';
string soqlParent = 'select id, (select '+fieldChild +' from '+relationName +') from '+sobjectParent +'where RecordType.Name=:contactRT';

database.query(soqlparent);
```

I get this exception `invalid alias recordtype.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space between sobjectparent and where. Change `'where` to `' where`.

Comment: I was staring at this for past 10-15mins ...you rock..it worked:)